# how to convert a JSON object to corresponding string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How can i convert the below JSON Object to a string that can be converted to string and stored in string field and then use it later to be converted back to JSON

The JSON is:

```
{"tds_head_id"=>88, "date"=>nil, "salary_gross_amount"=>0, "qualifying_amount"=>0, "proof_amount"=>0, "remarks"=>nil}
```

this hash has to be converted such that it can be converted back to the same JSON format later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of the JSON library generate method to do so and get the corresponding string like

```
json_object = {"tds_head_id"=>88, "date"=>nil, "salary_gross_amount"=>0, "qualifying_amount"=>0, "proof_amount"=>0, "remarks"=>nil}
JSON.generate(json_object)
```

output will be

```
  "{\"tds_head_id\":88,\"date\":null,\"salary_gross_amount\":0,\"qualifying_amount\":0,\"proof_amount\":0,\"remarks\":null}"
```

you can convert  it back to JSON by using JSON.parse Method